# Where does Kerberos TGT originated from? AS or TGS?

Tags: kerberos

I have been studying Kerberos, and I am confused with which component sent the **Ticket Granting Ticket(TGT)** from **KDC** back to the **Client**?

Some of the source I come across says, **TGT** originated from **Ticket Granting Service(TGS)**, which I think is very logically sounded, since it make sense that a ticket(i.e. TGT) is granted by a Ticker granting service.

However, some other source like these (https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fintroductiontokerberosauthentication.htm)

> The Authorization Server verifies the user’s access rights in the user database and creates a TGT and session key. The Authorization Sever encrypts the results using a key derived from the user’s password and sends a message back to the user workstation.

implies that **TGT** originated from **Authentication Service (AS)**.

So, my question is: where does Kerberos **TGT** originated from? **AS** or **TGS**? I am more toward AS myself based on the above source but would like more input on this topic, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TGT is a ticket issued to the `krbtgt` service. That's *all* it is. You can get tickets through either the AS or TGS flow.

In order to get a ticket from the *AS flow* you need to have what Kerberos calls long term credentials to initiate or complete the flow. The `AS-REP` contains a value encrypted to that long term credential, so it's only useful if you have the password (or certificate, or whatever).

In order to get a ticket from the *TGS flow* you need to have a ticket issued for `krbtgt`.

The *common* practice is to use the AS flow to request a ticket to `krbtgt` using your password as the long term credential (or certificate, or whatever). There's nothing stopping you from requesting a different service in the AS-REQ, it just happens that no one does it because it defeats the purpose of using a TGT in place of the creds. There are specific services this is special-cased for like password change though where this is the only way you can get a ticket (say your password is expired, you can't get a TGT, but can get a changepw ticket).

Once you have the TGT, you can request tickets to any other service using a `TGS-REQ`, including requesting another TGT by setting the service to `krbtgt` (it's effectively treated as a renew). The `TGS-REP` is returned to the client and contains the service ticket encrypted against the krbtgt session key. The client can decrypt it because it has the session key. Once it's decrypted the client converts it to an `AP-REQ` and hands it off to whatever application requested a ticket. The ticket in the AP-REQ is encrypted to the service password.